# Common regex for multiple data format strings

Tags: c#, regex

I have the data in the below format. The strings can be in any order, but a max of two entries on a line.
It can also have only one entry in a line. I'm trying hard from past two days to write a regex for the below conditions.

If I split the string with the number of spaces, the value is getting split. 
If I split the string with `)` if the value comes first before the occurrence of `)` as in line 1 or two, the string will not be split.
Any advice?

I defined the below regex that captures different part of the string.

```
\(([^)]+)\)
\(.+\)
```

However, I'm unable to build a regex that matches the data as below.

**Note**: Out of the 7 lines shown below, each line is an input string and not everything as a whole.

```
VALUE1                                PARAMETER(VALUE2)
VALUE3                                PARAMETER(VALUE4 WITH     SPACES)
PARAMETER(VALUE5)                     VALUE6
PARAMETER(VALUE7 WITH     SPACES)     VALUE8
PARAMETER(VALUE9 WITH     SPACES)     PARAMETER(VALUE10)
VALUE11                               VALUE12   
PARAMETER(VALUE13 WITH                                      SPACES)
```

to be captured as

```
VALUE1
PARAMETER(VALUE2)
VALUE3
PARAMETER(VALUE4 WITH     SPACES)
PARAMETER(VALUE5)
VALUE6
PARAMETER(VALUE7 WITH     SPACES)
VALUE8
PARAMETER(VALUE9 WITH     SPACES)
PARAMETER(VALUE10)
VALUE11
VALUE12
PARAMETER(VALUE13 WITH                                      SPACES)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use variable-width look-arounds to check if the multiple spaces are not inside parentheses:

```
(?<!\([^)]*)\s+(?![^(]*\))
```

See [RegexStorm Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c!%5c(%5b%5e)%5d*)%5cs%2b(%3f!%5b%5e(%5d*%5c))&i=VALUE1++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++PARAMETER(VALUE2)%0d%0aVALUE3++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++PARAMETER(VALUE4+WITH+++++SPACES)%0d%0aPARAMETER(VALUE5)+++++++++++++++++++++VALUE6%0d%0aPARAMETER(VALUE7+WITH+++++SPACES)+++++VALUE8%0d%0aPARAMETER(VALUE9+WITH+++++SPACES)+++++PARAMETER(VALUE10)%0d%0aVALUE11+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++VALUE12+++%0d%0aPARAMETER(VALUE13+WITH++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++SPACES))

**Regex Explanation:**

1. `(?<!\([^)]*)` - A negative look-behind that checks if the whitespace is NOT preceded with an opening `(` and optional number of characters other than `)` (i.e. the whitespace is not *after* the `(`)
2. `\s+` - Whitespace that will be consumed and left out of the final array after split **mind** that you can restrict it to only *spaces* with `\p{Zs}` shorthand Unicode class if you want to exclude tabs and other whitspace symbols that `\s`matches)
3. `(?![^(]*\))` - A negative look-ahead making sure there is no optional number of characters other than `(` and then `)` after the whitespace (i.e. there is no `)` after).

Points 1 and 3 make sure we are checking both sides of whitespace for parentheses.

You can use this regex with `Regex.Split()`.

```
var rx = new Regex(@"(?<!\([^)]*)\s+(?![^(]*\))");
var txt = @"YOUR TEXT";
var reslt = rx.Split(txt);
```

[image]

Comment: I used Royi Namir's and stribizhev's solutions.. Both work as expected.
Hope you guys did Ph.D in regex! Thanks guys..

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yes, in case you have "well-formed" input. It is only needed in case you have some weird input that may have "wild" `(` and `)`.

Comment: @stribizhev I dont understand can you provide example where `(?![^(]*\))` works ?

Comment: [Here is what I mean](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c!%5c(%5b%5e)%5d*)%5cs%2b&i=VALUE1++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++PARAMETERVALUE2). If you do not have such bad input, you can use the look-behind without the lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
(\S+\([^\)]+\)|\S+(?!\())
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eZ4oZ6/1)

`\S+\([^\)]+\)` matches non-whitespace, then an open bracket, then anything except a close bracket, then a close bracket.

`\S+(?!\())` match non-whitespace with negative lookahead for an open bracket.